# 'not inserted' -message is coming

Tags: php

Error is occurring in this code:

```
<?php
$con =mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
if(!$con)
{
echo 'Not connected To server';  
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'rk'))
{
echo 'Database not selected';
}
$Name=(isset($_POST['username']));
$Email=(isset($_POST['email']));
$passward=(isset($_POST['passward']));
$conformpassward=(isset($_POST['conformpassward']));
$sql="INSERT INTO rkgroup (name,email,passward,conformpassward) VALUES 
('$Name','$Email','$passward','$conformpassward')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo 'not submitted';
}
else
{
echo 'inserted';
}

?>
```

please give me some clues 
data is not stored in my database 
the error is coming in

Comment: You have a typo here if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql){ you miss a brackets. It must be brackets  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql) ){

Comment: if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql) , You have missed round bracket on that line
it must be if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ //Your code here }

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficient problem description. Unless you check for errors or showcase database schema and sample contents, this remains unanswerable either way. The horrible formatting doesn't help your matter. And as aside `$var = isset($_GET[xyz])` will merely leave a boolean, not the string. See also [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question and thus answers you can receive.

Comment: tell me what type of error i have done in this code

Comment: i have written problem in heading please see that

Answer (score 0):

You missed a bracket

```
   if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)
```

it should be

```
   if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```